# Who did Anakin replace on the Jedi Council?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, star-wars-legends, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin joins the Jedi Council.

The number of members seems to stay the same, at 12, so he must have replaced a member who either left the council or died.

Is it known which member he replaced and what happened to them?

I've seen some people claim he replaced  Even Piell, but I can find no proof of this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## He replaced Even Piell.

According to [this article](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-jedi-council-meet-the-masters) at the **official Star Wars web site**, between 22 BBY and 19 BBY Obi-Wan had replaced Saesee Tinn and Anakin had replaced Even Piell (amongst several other changes).

Here is a useful chart from the article:

[image]

As for Piell's fate, he was killed by an [Anooba](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anooba/Canon) during the Clone Wars — specifically the [Battle of Lola Sayu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lola_Sayu/Canon) — as seen in the episode ["Citadel Rescue"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel_Rescue) of the *Clone Wars* television series.

His death opened up a seat on the Council, which was filled by an overly eager Anakin during *Revenge of the Sith*.

Comment: I just read the full article and it says no such thing. He more likely replaced Rancisis.

Comment: @Conner : I can only speak to what I read at the linked URL in November 2015.